# Cannot assign to protected var in ci

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-form-helper

```
protected $_table_name = $this->session->userdata('table_name');
```

This my code while am trying to assign session data to this var , it shows error.

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\xampp\htdocs\Code\application\models\addfilters_m.php on line 4`

like this and here i have attached my whole model page

```
<?php
class addfilters_m extends MY_Model
{
protected $_table_name = $this->session->userdata('table_name');
protected $_order_by = 'id';
public $rules = array(
    'title' => array(
        'field' => 'title', 
        'label' => 'Title', 
        'rules' => 'trim|required|max_length[100]|xss_clean'
    ), 
    'slug' => array(
        'field' => 'slug', 
        'label' => 'Slug', 
        'rules' => 'trim|required|max_length[100]|url_title|callback__unique_slug|xss_clean'
    ), 
    'body' => array(
        'field' => 'body', 
        'label' => 'Body', 
        'rules' => 'trim|required'
    )
);

public function get_new ()
{
    $addfilters = new stdClass();
    $addfilters->title = '';
    $addfilters->slug = '';
    $addfilters->body = '';
    return $addfilters;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this approach which should be helpful to you and solve the issue.

```
protected  $_table_name;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->_table_name= $this->session->userdata("table_name");
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Comment: i tried this already , but i cant print that $_table_name in another function

Comment: I fixed the answer - in the other function you would write `echo $this->_table_name`